# Show that $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xz^2(x^2+z^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$ doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the Limit doesn't exist
$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xz^2(x^2+z^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$
I calculate the limit along $x=y=z$

so
$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac {x^5}{3x^4} = 0$

Then I try to use another curve. But to show that the limit doesn't exist, I can't showing two examples where the limit comes out to be different along different direction

Comment: What limit are you trying to solve? The one in the title and the one in the question don't match.

Comment: Try $y=z=\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$|x|,|y|,|z|\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$and that therefore\begin{align}0&\leqslant\left|\frac{xz^2(x^2+z^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\\&=3\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.\end{align}So, your limit does exist, and it is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong. Since $|x^{2}+z^{2}-y^{2}| \leq x^{2}+z^{2}+y^{2}$ we see that $|\frac {xz^{2}(x^{2}+z^{2}-y^{2})} { (x^{2}+z^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}\leq |x|$ so the limit exists and is $0$.